# GetLength() method does not work as expected on an array

Tags: c#

Here is a C# code.

It outputs the following text :

```
tab.Length = 6
tab.Rank = 2
Length of dim 0 of tab : 0
Length of dim 1 of tab : 1
```

I expected the following text :

```
tab.Length = 6
tab.Rank = 2
Length of dim 0 of tab : 2
Length of dim 1 of tab : 3
```

Why not? Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TableTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] tab = new int[2, 3];

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    tab[i, j] = 2 * i + j;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("tab.Length = {0}", tab.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("tab.Rank = {0}", tab.Rank);
            for (int i = 0; i < tab.Rank; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Length of dim {0} of tab : {0} ", i, tab.GetLength(i));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Wild guess: your last format string is wrong:

```
Console.WriteLine("Length of dim {0} of tab: {0} ", i, tab.GetLength(i));
```

You're using `{0}` twice, so you're outputting the value of `i` in both placeholders.

Use this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("Length of dim {0} of tab: {1} ", i, tab.GetLength(i));
```

Comment: @EdS. Well, it could've been a typo in the code sample, and I haven't really tested this. So "edumacated guesstimate" then.

Answer (score 1):

Your format string is wrong.

Replace `"Length of dim {0} of tab : {0} "` by `"Length of dim {0} of tab : {1} "`.

Your code was actually putting i, and not tab.GetLenght(i)

Answer (score 1):

Do you simply need to access the second parameter passed to the Console.WriteLine? Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Length of dim {0} of tab : {1} ", i, tab.GetLength(i));
```